# Sling - accessing properties via pageContext

Tags: java, performance, sling

To my understanding pageContext has access to many methods like 
getPage, getRequest, etc. So wouldn't it be better to simply access
what you need directly as oppose to using page context? The problem
is I have no idea how you would do this. So say I have this:

```
public void setProperties(PageContext context){
 ValueMap properties = (ValueMap) context.getAttribute("properties");
 Node currentNode = (Node) context.getAttribute("currentNode");

 pageHeader = properties.get("pageHeader", "")
}
```

That works fine.  How would you set what you specifically need? I have
this but it doesn't seem to work. I just get a **please check if the declared
type is right and if the method exists.

```
Resource resource = requestResolver.getResource("/content/my/resource");   

public void setProperties(){

ValueMap properties = (ValueMap) resource.getAttribute("properties");
Node currentNode = (Node) resource.getAttribute("currentNode");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to retrieve a ValueMap is to use the Adapter framework and to adapt the appropriate Resource or Node.
Both implement the Adaptable interface which enables you to adapt a Resource a number of target types like a Node, ValueMap and others.
http://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling6/org/apache/sling/api/adapter/Adaptable.html
http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/adapters.html

The following example shows how to retrieve a read only ValueMap

```
ValueMap properties = resource.adaptTo(ValueMap.class);
String propertyValue = values.get("propertyName", String.class);
```

If you need to modify the contents of the ValueMap then go for the PersistableValueMap.
http://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling6/org/apache/sling/api/resource/PersistableValueMap.html

```
PersistableValueMap valueMap = resource.adaptTo(PersistableValueMap.class);
valueMap.put(key,value);
valueMap.save();
```